# batch remove a substring variable from another string variable

Tags: string, batch-file, substring

I've got the following  code:

```
set "alpha=!alpha:%%~nxA=!
set "data=!data:%p2_dir%=!
```

which works regardless of what %p2_dir% value is,

now here's my problem, I would like to remove !alpha! from !data! and store it in a variable called dwa.

Example:

```
alpha=aaa\bbb\

data=aaa\bbb\ccc

dwa=ccc
```

in other topics they want to remove a variable like %substring% not !substring!

the problem is, since I've got 2 !var! variables I cannot use the following command:

```
"dwa=!data:!alpha!=!"
```

otherwise it returns

```
data:=
```

I tried sending values of !alpha! and !data! in a txt file then saving it using

```
set /p alpha2=< alpha.txt
```

but the result is still the same: alpha2 will be saved as !alpha2!

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show us a little bit more code in-context. There may be other ways of accomplishing whatever your requirement is.

Comment: `for /F %%a in ("!alpha!") do set "dwa=!data:%%a=!"`. I suggest you to carefully read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990/778560) although the topic seems to be different...

Comment: What Magoo is trying to lead you too is that if you are not inside a code block, there is no need to use delayed expansion for the inner variable. So we really need to see more of your code to understand in what context those lines are executing.

Comment: thx this is exactly what I was looking for @Aacini

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up using @Aacini answer:

```
set "alpha=!alpha:%%~nxA=!
set "data=!data:%p2_dir%=!
for /F %%a in ("!alpha!") do set "dwa=!data:%%a=!"
```

Comment: You could just use another SET command if you are not inside a code block.  Are you not understanding that concept?

Comment: Simpler: `for /F %%a in ("!alpha:%%~nxA=!") do set "dwa=!data:%%a=!"`